# Rails - Multiple top level domains and a single session/cookie

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, dns

I've been struggling with this for quite awhile and haven't been able to
find a solution. I need a user to be able to view multiple top level
domains with a single login.

My understanding is that this needs to be set in `environment.rb` and
called with `before_dispatch`. This is what I've come up with:

```
require 'activesupport'
require 'dispatcher'
module ActionController
   class Dispatcher

      def set_session_domain
         ActionController::Base.session_options.update :session_domain => "#{@request.host}"
      end 

      before_dispatch :set_session_domain
   end
end
```

However, this does not seem to be working when I try and pull the values
from `session[:session_domain]`.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: zenazn's response about the limitations of cookies is a good one.  Could anyone provide examples for one login across subdomains, at least?  Cookies should support that.  How does Rails?

Answer (score 8):

This one is a bit tricky. Since cookies can only be assigned to (and retrieved from) the current domain ("forms.example.com", say) and parent domains (".example.com", but not ".com"), but NOT to other domains ("othersite.com"), you'll have to find yourself another solution. This has nothing to do with Rails, but with how cookies work.

EDIT: Sessions rely on a client-specific handle, stored in a cookie, which is why sessions also don't work cross-domain.

[This site](http://www.theserverside.com/patterns/thread.tss?thread_id=31258) has one possible solution for creating a cross-domain cookie, and it's the cleanest way I know of, although it may have some security implications. A more complicated version would have the servers communicate directly through some secure channel.

If you're looking for a more general-purpose single-login service, try implementing some form of [OpenID](http://openid.net/).

Answer (score 2):

For sub-domains in Rails 2.3

```
ActionController::Base.session = { :domain => ".mydomain.com" }
```

For top-level domains try [this middleware](http://codetunes.com/2009/04/17/dynamic-cookie-domains-with-racks-middleware/).

I've been playing with the above middleware at the moment and it does not quite work as expected. If you do use the middleware you do not need the above code as it handles sub-domains as well.

Comment: The link listed here goes to a porn site, don't click.

Answer (score 1):

You will probably need something like RubyCAS if you want authentication across domains regardless of whether they're top-level or subdomains.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not really precise enough IMHO.  Do you want a single cookie for all Rails apps you have or is it within the context of a single one?  If the former, you want to look at solutions using database-backed sessions or something along the line of [RubyCAS](http://code.google.com/p/rubycas-client/) to implement the [CAS](http://www.ja-sig.org/products/cas/) protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Both Keltia and zuk are right, Answer is rubyCAS, We have do that integration and it allows

SSI - Single sign -in 
You sign to one site and you are automatically signed to the other

SSO - Single Sign Out
You sign out from one site and automatically you signed out from the other

For us this is a proven solution and not a hard one to implement

we are using it in
http://www.cabslk.com and www.ticketslk.com

cheers,
Sameera