# Retrieve session with session_id in Ruby On Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

I want to access the session of a user from a different domain than the one that I initiated the session. Can I use session.session_id of the user and then retrieve the session hash of that user ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

If it's on a different domain (i.e., not a subdomain), there's no way to get the session info (cause it's stored in a cookie)—you'll need something else (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/377137/rails-multiple-top-level-domains-and-a-single-session-cookie#378072)). If it's a subdomain, I think there's a neat way to do it automatically by setting the cookie's domain (look in environment.rb's `config.action_controller.session`, try setting `:session_domain`)

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you could use something like:

```
CGI::Session::ActiveRecordStore::SqlBypass::find_by_session_id(session_id)
```

However, I'm not sure if that's a good idea or not -- and in this case it is only useful if you're using the ActiveRecordStore.  Not sure what else is available on the other stores, but if you poke around under actionpack/lib/action_controller/session/* you'll probably get a more definitive answer.